# noob Q: layout_below not placing my button below my textView

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Very new so please excuse misuse of terms.

I'm following an Android development course to build a basic app.  I created a text view and then a button.  The button should sit below the text view after using `android:layout_below="@id/rollResult"` but instead the button overlaps the text.

Adding and removing that line from my code has no effect on the botton's layout position.  Changing this line `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` from true to false and back also has no effect.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.diceout.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rollResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="The play App"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rollButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/rollResult"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="rollDice"
    android:text="Roll" />
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ConstraintLayout` to `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Wow, Thanks! That worked. Everything lines up now as it should.